# How to secure individual fields

Tags: users

I am looking for a good way to add security at a field level based on a group.  Different groups will use the same content type. Does OG handle this requirement. I don't want to make the full node private.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for [Field Permission](https://drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module. It says :

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.